# How to ban results from Solr for particular keywords in searched string

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I need a way to block results for search strings if one of the keyword from the set of keywords will match.

Ex:
Lets say a user searches for "bad restaurant" in his search query, How do i block all results for such a query string with keyword "bad".

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a StopFilterFactory. StopFilterFactory is usually used to filter out stopwords like 'a', 'and', 'the' etc... But one could just as well specify 'other' keywords as stopwords.

Here's an example. Note that I only use the StopFilterFactory during querying, hence it's only included for the 'query' analyzer. The 'profanity_words.txt' lists all to-be-excluded words.

```
<fieldType name="soundex" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/profanity_words.txt"></filter>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="Soundex" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do this using filterQueries and preparing the filter on application side.
There are different ways to do this.
If there are only a 2 or 3 "bad" words, you could add an filter query, like that:

`localhost:8080/?q=bad restaurant&fq=MY_TEXTFIELD:bad`

(probably you have to use `+` for space `bad+restaurant` and `%3A`  for `:`

If you have some more "protected words" you can use an synonym list and an token, like that:

`localhost:8080/?q=bad restaurant&fq=MY_TEXTFIELD:qwasyxerdfcv`

```
synonyms.txt
qwasyxerdfcv,bad,fucking,terrible
```

you also could use explicit mapping, depending when you apply this synonyms.

Comment: actually, really weird solution, really suited only for a couple of bad words